# How to highlight lowest n values with duplicates in Excel?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am looking for some help in using conditional highlighting to show the bottom 3 values in a data set. The data set contains 18 values and can only contain 0 or 3.

Here are some examples and what should be expected:

#### Example 1

```
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

The bottom 3 values would be three 3s.

#### Example 2

```
3 0 0 3 3 0 0 3 0 3 0 3 3 3 0 3 3 0
```

The bottom 3 values would be three 0s.

#### Example 3

```
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 3 3
```

The bottom 3 values would be the two 0s and one 3.

I have tried using the built-in formatting rule "Format only top or bottom ranked values" and set bottom and 3 for the rule description as well as using a formula with the `SMALL` function but this does not work for values where there are less than or more than 3 instances of the bottom ranked value (aka, ties in the rank). I know I need a second criteria to make sure a value is one of the bottom ranked 3 values and is one of the firstly ranked 3 values in the data set as well. Therefore, not only the value has to be ranked in the bottom 3 values but also it has to be the first 3 values in the bottom 3 values. I am just not sure how to go about this and I could not find a resource that explains how to solve this issue with duplicates. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have to sort by value and column I think

```
=MATCH(COLUMN(A2),SORTBY(COLUMN($A2:$R2),$A2:$R2,1,COLUMN($A2:$R2),1),0)<=3
```

[image]